# Align three cards horizontally in a single row dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, rest, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the card one next to other. I've done the below coding not sure why am I not able display it one next to other.

Here I am trying to call REST API and the result I get from REST API is a list I need to iterate the result through for loop and then display the fetched data in card form. Please someone guide me through this, thank you..

**client.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
        $.ajax({
           url: "REST API CALL",
           success: function(data){        
            data.forEach(function(a) { 
                var html = `      
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
                    <img class="imagee" src="im.png" alt="image" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
                     <div class="card-body">
                     ${a[0]}|${a[4]}<br>
                     ${a[7]}<br>
                     <i class="fa fa-car"></i>${a[9]}
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
           </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

                $('#msgs').append(`<div>${html}</div>`);
              });
             }
        }).then(function(data) {      
        });
        });
```

Comment: what was the issue? and expected output

Comment: You are using bootstrap? Remove the `<div class="">` cause it doesnt do anything and change the div class card to `<div class="card col-4">` (and remove the width and inline-block in style="...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for guiding me find a solution. Here is a solution I found to align the cards horizontally in for loop using col-lg-3.

```
     var html = ` 
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

            <div class="col-lg-3" ng-app=""><br>
            <div  class="card" style="width:20em;text-align:center;"><br>
              <img ng-if="'${a[2]}'=='null'" src="image" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">

               <div class="card-body">
                &nbsp;${a[0]} &nbsp;| &nbsp;${a[4]}<br>

                 &nbsp;${a[7]}<br></td>
                 <tr><td>
                 &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bed"></i>&nbsp; ${a[1]} &nbsp;

</div>
  </div><br>
</div>`

$('#msgs').append(`<div>${html}</div>`);

          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code underneath, and put the `<div class="row">` outside of this function and around the html item that has an `id="msgs"`, since the `div class row` needs to be around all of the card elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "REST API CALL",
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(a) {
        var html = `      
                <div class="card col-4" style="text-align:center;">
                    <img class="imagee" src="im.png" alt="image" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        ${a[0]}|${a[4]}<br>
                        ${a[7]}<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-car"></i>${a[9]}
                        <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        $("#msgs").append(`<div>${html}</div>`);
      });
    }
  }).then(function(data) {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add class `col-md-4` to div inside the div of class `row`

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $.ajax({
       url: "REST API CALL",
       success: function(data){        
        data.forEach(function(a) { 
            var html = `      
            <div class="row">
               <div class="">
                <div class="card colo-md-4" style="width: 20rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
                <img class="imagee" src="im.png" alt="image" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
                 <div class="card-body">
                 ${a[0]}|${a[4]}<br>
                 ${a[7]}<br>
                 <i class="fa fa-car"></i>${a[9]}
              <p class="card-text"></p>
       </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>`

            $('#msgs').append(`<div>${html}</div>`);
          });
         }
    }).then(function(data) {      
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The rendering logic in the forEach needs to change. Repeat the columns, and then put all the columns in a `row`

```
     data.forEach(function(a) { 
        html += `      
           <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="width:20em;text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
                <img class="imagee" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="image" height="200" width="200" style="border-radius:.60rem;">
                 <div class="card-body">
                 `+a[0]+`<br>
                 <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
                  <p class="card-text"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>`;
     });
     $('#msgs').append(`<div class="row">`+html+`</div>`);
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Xh54qLX5xp